# node-tunnel/node-https: If authentication parameters are bad or any proxy parameter is bad, exceptions are thrown

Tags: node.js, https, electron, http-proxy

We are using node-tunnel (https://github.com/koichik/node-tunnel) for proxy requests in our electron application.
if authentication parameters are bad or any proxy parameter is bad, exceptions are thrown.. Is there a way to catch these exceptions and show to the user what went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you can use try catch in your project to catch the error and once you catch the error you can show it to the user

```
try {
  console.log("entering try block");
  throw "thrown message";
  console.log("this message is never seen");
}
catch (e) {
  console.log("entering catch block");
  console.log(e);
  console.log("leaving catch block");
}
finally {
  console.log("entering and leaving the finally block");
}
```

Comment: I tried try-catch in https request.. It is not working because of async nature. This exception is thrown from thirdparty module .. SO far unable to catch that